# Adding Uri object to .child() command

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, runtime-error

im trying to override an object in my realtime database, by doing this command:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(user.getUid().toString()).setValue(user);
```

(user) is the updated user, and user.getUid() gives me the uid of this object in the database, however , i see in the logcat , that this command gives me an URI which looks like this:

```
Log.w("THE URI IS= ",FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(user.getUid().toString())+"");
```

LOGCAT RESULT:

> W/THE URI IS=: https://mydatabase.firebase/User/nfKQA6TwsQNTyYUbxrmF08U77Pq2

i only want the nfKQA6TwsQNTyYUbxrmF08U77Pq2, and if i put the `user.getUid()` alone in the logcat it shows what i want without the uri.

my db:

[image]

worth mentioning that if i keeep the command its throwing a very long error AndroidRuntime:

> at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:47)

Comment: It is hard to understand what you're trying to do. I gave it a try below. If that is not what you're looking for, edit your question to more clearly describe what you want as the output from the code. If you want help with the error message, edit your question to include the exact error message and its stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log the UID of the user, you'd just do:

```
Log.w("THE URI IS= "+user.getUid());
```

Note there is no need to call `toString()` here, since `getUid()` already returns a string.